# How can I select max id in MySQL in the fastest way considering time complexity

Tags: mysql

Which would be the best way to find the biggest ID in MySQL?

I am working on an eCommerce website and I need to find the maximum ID.

But regarding big table size and high frequency of using database by web application, I would like to know more how MySQL finding the biggest ID in MAX() way.

The only two method I know is that:

1. Sorting and cut column one
2. MAX(id)

Comment: The easiest way is to have an indexed or primary key id, and then sort by id desc.

Comment: Yah, But I would like to know how MySQL working, and using want kind of algorithm

Comment: For what purpose are you using the maximum id? There are many uses frequently attempted that will fall based on race conditions. There are usually good solutions to those that are robust.

Comment: @danblack I just want to insert data row. 
Humm, race condition could also happen. I didn't consider it before....
Maybe LOCK TABLES before inserting?

Comment: If you want to insert rows, make the column auto_increment, do the insert, an the id value will be returned though the API on what that inserted value is. Always consider that databases know how to search data and manage concurrency well. Look for the interfaces that allow them to do so. If in doubt, ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ with a high level objective. Never resort to explicit locking or user invented locking constructs.

Comment: Thank you so much @danblack ! MySQL can add id increment automatically even I miss this column, I tried this before. But I do not know whether it is a good way to miss this column when I insert rows.

Comment: you can miss columns, and its a good idea if you depend on its default value like auto_increment, or if you want the default value for the column (potentially `NULL`).

Comment: @danblack OK! I got it! Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Databases are good at data. MySQL correctly indexed is no exception.

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM tablename
```

So keep it simple.

This will scan backwards though a `id` based index to find the maximum number.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a resistant variable so that every time a new record is added to the table the max_tableA_id variable gets updated so it is always within easy reach.

Alternately you could create a simple table with two columns...
table names and current max id
and then update the appropriate record each time a new record is added to the table.

now all you need is a simple query to get the current max id for a given table.

Comment: The problem is concurrency. Inserts don't always have access to the same max_tableA_id variable. Selecting a max value is only valid for that instance, the microsecond later a new value will be there, so you can't depend on its value to hold in the next SQL query. Workarounds of database functionality will only end in pain.

Comment: Regarding concurrency... if a zillion records per second are being added to a tableA and some task needs the current max_tableA_id... then, of course it will be old by the time it is retrieved... no matter how you do it... I would think. Any "get" would always be "at the instant I got this... here is what it was" Right? Or did I mis-understand your point... and/or the OP's question?

Comment: the direction and purpose of getting the maximum changed by virtue of the followup comments to the point the maximum was no longer required. Even without this going through convoluted ways should only be considered once the simple solutions are proved inadequate.